# Flutter Geocoding package not working on IOS, any solutions?

Tags: iphone, flutter, dart, geolocation

Flutter Geocoding package not working on IOS

Hi guys, in my application with flutter 3.7.12 i need to convert a coordenate to get the city Name from the position, and i have installed the package `geocoding: ^2.1.0` But when i try to build on IOS i get this error does anyone know what it could be? on android it works good. i receive the error `geocoding_ios module is not found`

follow the prints bellow:

[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Dnp.png)

[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Yho.png)

[photo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g6RS.png)

[photo4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5lyt.png)

I've already tries to use pod deintegrate, pod update and pod install, flutter clean, flutter pub get and flutter build ios, tried to change the ios target from 15.0 to 14.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps below

Go to your `ios` directory:

1. Delete `.symlinks` folder.
2. Delete `Pods` folder.
3. Delete `Podfile.lock`
4. Run `flutter pub get`
5. `cd ios` and run `pod install --repo-update`